# Mysql group by and count attempts on seperate column

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a mySQL query that groups results by quiz attempt ID:

```
SELECT * 
FROM quiz_log  
WHERE archived = 0 
GROUP BY quiz_attempt_id 
ORDER BY quiz_attempt_id ASC
```

[image: This produces the below result]

My question is how do I now count up the attempts in the by `app_user_id`. The `app_user_id = 150` appears three times, so I need another column with the number 1 on the first line, 2 on the 3rd line and 3 on the 19th line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated query:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT count(distinct s.quiz_attempt_id) FROM quiz_log s
        WHERE s.app_user_id = t.app_user_id
         AND s.timestamp <= t.timestamp) as Your_Cnt
FROM quiz_log t
WHERE ....
```

Comment: SELECT t.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM quiz_log s WHERE s.app_user_id = t.app_user_id AND s.timestamp <= t.timestamp) as Your_Cnt FROM quiz_log t GROUP BY quiz_attempt_id I have just tried, but it shows the Your_cnt column as 1 then 11 then 21?